# add user to CIVICRM with Wordpress

Tags: user

I need to add a new CIVI CRm user, how can I do that please???

I used to do that before but i forgot how to do it now.

I tried Users and Permissions but it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

If you need to synchronise the user from WP to CiviCRM you can do it by

1) Navigate to `Administer -> Users and Permissions -> Synchronize Users to Contacts`.

2) Click `OK` on the form that says to synchronise cms users.